# Wait for another request before responding

Tags: javascript, node.js

I actually have nearly no JS background at all, but I still need to do a little of communication over a WebServer running NodeJS for a current project.

Following task: A client sends a post request /route1 . The server processes the task, but before it responses, it needs to wait for the post request /route2 of another client.

How can I do so?

I found something about promises and await/async but I do not totally understand it and am not sure if this is actually what I am looking for.

```
app.post('/route1', function (req, res) {
      //send a respond only after /route2 was called


});


app.post('/route2', function (req, res) {


})
```

Comment: This design approach is one that is likely to lead to a really awful user experience. If the other client doesn't respond quickly enough, then the first request is going to time out. Look at using WebSockets if you need to send a message to a client in response to a message from a different client.

Comment: "...it needs to wait for the post request /route2 of another client." ...that just isn't how HTTP works at all. In theory you could be waiting forever. Or the request to route2 could have occurred before the other one. Or you could have 20 route2 requests and can't distinguish. HTTP is a stateless, disconnected protocol. Each request is entirely independent from every other. Can you explain the actual situation and what you are trying to achieve? Then we can potentially suggest a more viable architecture. As Quentin says, it sounds like WebSockets might be useful, but we need more info first

Comment: How will you match the two requests? Do they have to be from the same ip/user/machine...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Preface:** Having a POST response wait for another POST before it can be sent seems like a problematic setup. I'd suggest avoiding it if at all possible.

---

You need a way to relate the requests, so we know which `/route2` request satisfies which previous `/route1` request. You can do that by

1. Assuming that the last `/route1` request should be satisfied by the current `/route2` request (which is simple, but seems fragile)
2. Including identifying information in the requests (some kind of common ID)

Then store the requests/responses outside of the functions. If you're going for #1 above, you just need a single variable:

```
let lastRoute1 = null;

app.post('/route1', (req, res) => {
    lastRoute1 = {req, res};
});

app.post('/route2', (req, res) => {
    if (!lastRoute1) {
        // Error, we were expecting a previous /route1 request
    } else {
        // Send response via `lastRoute1.res` (and presumably respond here, too, via `res`)

        // Done with it
        lastRoute1 = null;
    }
});
```

But again, that seems fragile. Perhaps a `Map` of outstanding requests:

```
let route1Requests = new Map();

app.post('/route1', (req, res) => {
    const id = /*...get ID from `req`...*/;
    route1Requests.set(id, {req, res, tstamp: Date.now()});
});

app.post('/route2', (req, res) => {
    const id = /*...get ID from `req`...*/;
    const route1 = route1Requests.get(id);
    if (!route1) {
        // Error, we were expecting a previous /route1 request
    } else {
        // Send response via `route1.res` (and presumably respond here, too, via `res`)

        // Done with it
        route1Requests.remove(id);
    }
});
```

Perhaps add a timer to do a timeout on ones that haven't been dealt with...

Comment: you left some arrows to your es5 functions

Comment: @Zoti - Thanks. Actually, I just copied the OP's and didn't notice the syntax error. :-) Fixed now.

Comment: Whoops, sry for the syntax error. Fixed it in the answer too. 

Also thank you very much for your answer. I think you are right, that the whole setup is not stable at all. I think I will still implement it for a showcase and then explain, why we should rework the current solution.

Comment: *Fixed it in the question too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use Event Emitters for this task. But I don't think this task relies on the real world. Because you have two services which can connect multiple clients. so that means other clients also have to wait. So for the given task, you can use this example:

```
const myEmitter = new MyEmitter();

app.post('/route1',(req, res) => {
    myEmitter.on('event', (message) => {
        res.send(message);
    });
});


app.post('/route2', (req, res) => {
    myEmitter.emit('event', 'message from route 2');
    res.send('route 2 sent message to route 1');
})
```

Better approach will be using **WebSockets**.